# kotlin: what is the best way to determine if 2 lists have any common element?

Tags: list, algorithm, performance, kotlin, optimization

What is the best way to find if 2 lists have at least one element in common? I am trying to do this in kotlin and while this is quite easy, I wanted to explore which is the best way to do this.

Problem:

```
fun isAnyElementCommon(
    alist: List<String>,
    blist: List<String>
):Boolean
```

one example would be:

`= alist.intersect(blist).isNotEmpty()`

but I think that is too much processing to find out *all* the common values and then checking if it is empty

**EDIT**

another would be:

`= alist.any{ blist.contains(it) }`

I am aware of these solutions. I just wanted to know if there are better ways to approach this problem. If not, then that is also fine. I am looking for a low complexity and low memory footprint solution. Also, in kotlin, most cases are covered by some helper extension functions. So maybe if there is anything like this. I would like to know.

Comment: You could classically iterate one list and check if the other one contains the current element, then stop at the first match. Will be a lot of processing for the worst case (no common element), too. Maybe compare performance of both ideas...

Comment: If you want to optimize time, use a map/dictionary. If space is more important, use sorting and binary search for O(NlogN)

Comment: [Is your question answered?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni no, the only good answer only solves it in one way. the comment has better solution but it is not in the form of an answer

Answer (score 7):

To get it down to *O(n)*, convert one list to a Set first.

```
fun isAnyElementCommon(
    aList: List<String>,
    bList: List<String>
):Boolean {
    val aSet = aList.toSet()
    return bList.any { it in aSet }
}
```

Comment: toSet is expensive. it creates a new set

Comment: Still cheaper than *O(n^2)*. Maybe if your lists have fewer than ~ten elements the allocation time might not be worth it. But maybe you’re more memory conscious than speed conscious.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not Kotlin-esque enough, but Java's `Collections.disjoint()` is optimized for this:

```
fun isAnyElementCommon(
    alist: List<String>,
    blist: List<String>
):Boolean =
    !Collections.disjoint(aList, bList)
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Put one list into a hash map.
2. Iterate over second list and return true if an element from second list is present in hash map.